# Nodejs : download image from url

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, download, imagedownload

I have React.js and Node.js application. In that application I need to download image from URL like normal downloads which get stored in Download/specified path.

I have tried many methods from frontend (React) as well as backend (node.js by calling api to save image).
Unfortunately most of solution opening image in new tab, some downloading file in unsupported format.

Some code tried in Node.js like below:

1.

```
router.post("/downloadImage", auth, async (req, res) => {
res.download('https://help.twitter.com/content/dam/help-twitter/brand/logo.png');
});
```

2. router.post("/downloadImage", auth, async (req, res) => {
   res.attachment("https://help.twitter.com/content/dam/help-twitter/brand/logo.png");
   });
3. 

with `image-downloader` library https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-downloader

```
router.post("/downloadImage", auth, async (req, res) => {
 try{
    const desktopDir = path.join(os.homedir(), "Downloads");
    console.log(desktopDir);
   
    const options = {
      url: 'https://help.twitter.com/content/dam/help-twitter/brand/logo.png',
      dest: 'C:\Users\Ganesh\Downloads"             // will be saved to /path/to/dest/image.jpg
    };

    download.image(options)
    .then(({ filename }) => {
      console.log('Saved to', filename); // saved to /path/to/dest/image.jpg
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
} catch (e) {
  console.log('error here',e);
  logger.error(e.message);
  res.send("error found");
}
  });
```

Above works for   `dest: 'C:\Users\Ganesh\Downloads'` and gives 403 error for **dest: `${desktopDir}`** . I am not able to figure it out how should I make `dest` dynamic for all device's Download folder with permission so it will get download.

Please help
Thanks

Comment: If I may ask, what is in the console.log(desktopDir); when you print it?

Comment: @RamuNarasinga it prints correctly like C:\Users\Ganesh\Downloads but gives if use that for dest - Error: Request Failed 403, might have permission issue when we use 'path' and if statically given stores as expected

Comment: You don't need to define it as ${desktopDir}, can be directly used as a variable desktopDir, even better if you just change it to const dest= path.join(os.homedir(), "Downloads"); and then  const options = {
      url: 'https://help.twitter.com/content/dam/help-twitter/brand/logo.png',
      dest
    };
Try the above and let me know.